# How to catch connection error with NodeJs MySql2 library async/await

Tags: node.js, async-await, shared-libraries

The doc on [NPM and GitHub](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) doesn't show how to catch an exception when making a connection.  I was guessing, based on how the query method works.  So as a newbie to a new library, do I have to read the code to figure it out? Or is there some common standard practice that I'm missing?  I put in a bad password on purpose just to test the error handling.

Should I do a try/catch, or expect an err object to be returned?  Is it inconsistent if they return an err object on the query method but not the connection method?

Using Amazon AWS Aurora as data store.

const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
GetData();

```
async function GetData() {

    const config = require("config");
    const dbConfig =  config.get('AWS.Database01TestErr');  
    console.log ("const dbConfig:"); 
    console.dir(dbConfig, { depth: null });

    const [errConn, connection] = await mysql.createConnection(dbConfig);
    if (errConn) throw errConn;
    mysql.createConnection(dbConfig);
    console.log ("Got the database connection"); 

    //query = "select ID, user_nicename, user_email from wp_users where user_login = 'hebgadmin' ";
    query = "select ID, user_nicename from wp_users limit 3 ";
    console.log ("Starting query"); 

    const [rows, fields, err] = await connection.query (query); 
    if (err) throw err;
    // console.log(rows); 

    console.log("Show Data Retrieved");   
    rows.map(e=>{ 
          console.log("ID="+ e.ID + " NiceName=" + e.user_nicename); 
     })   

    console.log ("The end"); 
    process.exit();   // Else Node hangs and must hit cntl-break to exit 

}
```

Partial Output:

> (node:2836) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Access denied for
>   user 'adm test1'@'10.1.2.123' (using password: YES)
>       at Object.createConnection (D:\Project2\POC\node_modules\mysql2\promise .js:223:31)
>       at GetData (D:\Project2\POC\mySqlQuery_V3_Await.js:34:44)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes try...catch is the pattern with async/await

here is the mdn which has some discussion on errors:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

here is similar code from the mongodb docs showing try...catch:

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/reference/ecmascriptnext/crud/

Comment: If that's the pattern then why does query return an error object?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know, but check out these comments:  https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/issues/945#issuecomment-482033389, https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/issues/945#issuecomment-481948337, https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/issues/998#issue-479913538

Answer (score 2):

```
function connect() {    
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    let connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host: 'hostname',
      user: 'username',
      password: 'password',
      database: 'db'
    })

    connection.connect(err => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err)
      } else {
        resolve(true)
      }
    })  

  })
}
```